# Pulling vs. Carrying

Tags: backpacking, wilderness

I've done a lot of backpacking in my home state of Colorado.  My pack and its contents is pretty light but not "ultralight", maybe 20 pounds including food.

I'm considering something like these for the Colorado Trail:

- https://www.competitivecyclist.com/weehoo-igo-cargo-bike-trailer
- https://www.quietkat.com/product/2019-quietkat-cargo-trailer/

[image: cargo bike trailer]

[image: cargo bike trailer]

They are designed to be pulled by bikes but I think I could attach to my waist by straps.  I don't have any physical limitations, I'm just intrigued by the possibility of leveraging the mechanical advantage of the wheel.  And I wonder if this would classify as "mechanized" transport and thus not allowed in wilderness areas.

Comment: How is the terrain on the trail? If it is a bit rugged having wheels may actually be a disadvantage

Comment: Also can you shortly describe the device you link to? Links tend to rot over time (and the first one already now isn't reachable outside of the US).

Comment: Thanks everyone, I marked the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Since you are already traveling pretty light compared to most, this would be an utter waste of your money and effort on such a rough trail. This would only be useful on fairly flat surfaces with heavier loads, similar to using a pulk over snow.